# Greedy regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-greedy

I am working on the following regex:

```
var match = string.match(/(?:(normal|italic|oblique))?\s*(?:(normal|small-caps))?\s*(?:((?:normal|bold|bolder|lighter|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px)))\/?)?\s*((?:(?:xx-small|x-small|small|medium|large|x-large|xx-large|larger|smaller|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))\s*){1,2})?\s*(?:(normal|inherit|\d+(?:\%|in|cm|mm|em|rem|ex|pt|pc|px))\s*)?\s*(?:([a-zA-Z\-\,\'\"\s]+)\s*)?(?:,|;)(?:(caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar)\s*)?/i);
```

The string is:

```
var string = "font: normal small-caps fantasy, sans-serif;"
```

I need each of the values to be returned to their proper place in the match array however one of the matches is being too greedy. The result is this:

```
match[1] = "normal"
match[2] = "small"
match[6] = "-caps fantasy, sans-serif"
```

I need the result to be:

```
match[1] = "normal"
match[2] = "small-caps"
match[6] = "fantasy, sans-serif"
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You forgot to escape your `-`s, for one thing.

Comment: @Doorknob where is the un-escaped - ?

Comment: When I test you code in a Fiddle, `match[1]` is `undefined`, `match[2]` is `normal` and `match[6]` is `-caps fantasy, sans-serif`: see http://jsfiddle.net/tC7T7/. This makes me think that there's something wrong outside the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Make the last part non greedy, instead of `([a-zA-Z\-\,\'\"\s]+)` do:

```
([a-zA-Z\-\,\'\"\s]+?)
```

And there no needs to escape all these characters:

```
([-a-zA-Z,'"\s]+?)
```